# UIScrollView detect when user drags scroll bars

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

On iOS 13 and above, it's possible to tap and hold on the scrollbars in a scrollview, then drag them to scroll.

Is there a programatic way to detect when this happens (as opposed to regular scrolling)?

Comment: I couldn’t find any delegate for this, but what do you want to achieve

Comment: The bottom sheet on the Apple maps a app will dismiss as you scroll beyond the top of the scrollview - but not if you use the scrollbar